# get captcha from web site

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm trying to create an app to login in a site and get some information .

I'm still getting some **problem with captcha** I got the code of the site and how I can requesto from the site the id and use this kind of **scripts into xcode**

SITE CODE EXAMPLE

```
<name="security_code"> img id="siimage" src="//www.EXAMPLE.com/image/captcha?sid=0.33785829535271394" alt="Aguarde...">

<a class="muted" onclick="document.getElementById('siimage').src = '//www.EXAMPLE.com/image/captcha?sid=' + Math.random(); return false" title="Refresh Image" href="#" tabindex="-1">
```

MY XCODE

```
NSString *CapId = @"http://www.EXAMPLE.com/image/captcha?sid=0.9572159171447838";       labelCID.text = CapId; 

[captcha1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CapId]]]; 

NSString *CapId2 = [captcha1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('%@').src ='//www.EXAMPLE.com/image/captcha?sid=' + Math.random();", CapId]; 

NSLog(@"CapId2: %@", CapId2);
```

thanks

Comment: sorry to say but its very messy, pls could you post the site itself **OR** captcha they are using like Recaptcha or NPL captcha etc...

Comment: Karan , Sorry for this , I'm new in this site and with xcode ...
here is the oficial site that I can use the xcode 

<img id="siimage" src="//www.telexfree.com/image/captcha?sid=a58fcafedd122981986fe5d580900000" alt="Aguarde..."></img>

<a class="muted" onclick="document.getElementById('siimage').src = '//www.telexfree.com/image/captcha?sid=' + Math.random(); return false" title="Refresh Image" href="#" tabindex="-1">

I want just use this captcha in my xcode to make the correct login.